# Сумма одного значения в объекте jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, объекты

```
   var bets = [{id: 1, value: 250},
               {id: 2, value: 200},
               {id: 3, value: 100}];
            for(var key in bets) {
                  var bets = bets[key];
            }
```

Как мне посчитать всю сумму значения `value`? А то есть сложить данные `value` из всех 3 объектов.

Comment: а есть какая-то веская причина того, что в массиве указаны строки со значениями, а не, например, объекты с ключом-значением?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский подправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тогда всё просто: применяем **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** с первоначальным значением ноль. Reduce  применяет функцию к аккумулятору и каждому значению массива (слева-направо), сводя его к одному значению

```js
var bets = [{id: 1, value: 250},
               {id: 2, value: 200},
               {id: 3, value: 100}];
               
var total = bets.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev + curr.value;
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var bets = [
  {id: 1, value: 250},
  {id: 2, value: 200},
  {id: 3, value: 100}
];

var sum = 0;
for(var key in bets) {
      sum += bets[key].value;
}

console.log(sum);
```